# EL expressions evaluating to empty string

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm new to JSP and JSTL, so I'm probably doing something really dumb here.

I have javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1 and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1 in my webapps's lib directory.  I'm running on Tomcat7.  If it makes any difference, tomcat is being launched by Eclipse.  My project is a "Dynamic Web Project".

**web.xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
        <display-name>example</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp** looks like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String s = "Foo";
    %>
    <c:out value="${s}" />
    <c:out value="Bar" />
</body>
</html>
```

I expect this to display a page with `Foo Bar` on it.  Instead, it displays just `Bar`.  This happens with all my EL expressions.  All my EL expressions seem to be coming up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen your self-answer but that's not the right way:

If you're already using JSTL with `c:out`s anyway avoid using scriptlets altogether and replace

```
<%
    request.setAttribute("s", "Foo");
%>
```

with this:

```
<c:set var="s" value="Foo" scope="request"/>
```

then printing the value would be:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.s}"/>
```

or simply `${requestScope.s}` since the `c:out` tag isn't really necessary unless you need to scape XML characters.

(`${s}` is also fine since the cointainer searches in all the scopes until it finds the first occurrence but, explicitly writting it is cleaner imo)

Comment: [Where](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) do you read that `<c:out>` is deprecated?

Comment: @BalusC I'd sweard I read it somewhere but can't find it so it seems I was mistaken. Removed that from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was just me not understanding EL.

Instead of

```
<%
    String s = "Foo";
%>
```

It should be:

```
<%
    request.setAttribute("s", "Foo");
%>
```